# PHP - sort array by pattern

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings

```
[ "one", "Two", "FOUR", "Four", "three", "two"]
```

I need to create a string that looks like this:

"one, three, two

one, Two, three, Four, two

one, Two, FOUR, three, Four, two".

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: So can you actually explain the logic behind these patterns?

Comment: And the pattern is? In your mind?

Comment: I honestly cannot see the logic in your desired output. Usually there has to be some kind of logic to make a general function. Otherwise you would need a very specific function to handle edge cases.

Comment: In first row only lowercase strings. In second row, one lowercase, one first letter uppercase and so on. In third row, one lowercase, next one is first letter uppercase and then uppercase and so on until there are elements in array.

Comment: ok, what have you tried?

Comment: So you actually need to do some filtering before your sort.... looking at [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) would be a good starting point then

Comment: So... did you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires PHP >= 5.4 for short array syntax

```
$master = [ "one", "Two", "FOUR", "Four", "three", "two"];

// Filter $master into arrays containing the appropriate lower, ucfirst and upper values
$lowerSet = array_filter(
    $master,
    function($value) {
        return strtolower($value) == $value;
    }
);

$ucfirstSet = array_filter(
    $master,
    function($value) {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($value)) == $value;
    }
);

$upperSet = array_filter(
    $master,
    function($value) {
        return strtoupper($value) == $value;
    }
);

function sorting(array $series) {
    $mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
    foreach($series as $valueSet) {
        $mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($valueSet));
    }
    $line = [];
    foreach($mi as $values) {
        $line = array_merge($line, $values);
    }
    return array_filter($line);
}

$lines = [
    implode(', ', $lowerSet),
    implode(', ', sorting([$lowerSet, $ucfirstSet])),
    implode(', ', sorting([$lowerSet, $ucfirstSet, $upperSet]))
];
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
```

but will work with PHP >= 5.3 if `[]` is replaced with `array()`